# Column definition for a SQL Server equivalent to Access BOOLEAN type

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, ddl

The BOOLEAN datatype in Access (ie, Jet/ACE) returns a -1 for True and 0 for False; the field is always required (i.e., it cannot be set to NULL).  The SQL Server BIT type returns 1 for True and 0 for False and also allows NULLs.

I'm looking for a T-SQL column definition using a combination of smallint, check constraints, and NOT NULL to replicate the functionality of the Jet/ACE BOOLEAN datatype.  In other words, the column would only accept the values 0 and -1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To address your concerns about BIT:

1. You can set your BIT column to NOT NULL.
2. You can use -1 when *setting* a BIT column to "true".
3. You can create a view that translates to -1, but +1 should be fine anyway unless your application explicitly checks for the numeric -1 (anything but zero should yield true in your client language).

```sql
CREATE TABLE dbo.foo(bar BIT NOT NULL, blat BIT NOT NULL);

INSERT dbo.foo SELECT -1, 0;

SELECT bar, blat, -CONVERT(SMALLINT, bar), -CONVERT(SMALLINT, blat) FROM dbo.foo;
```

Results:

```
bar   blat   
----  ----  ----  ----
1     0     -1    0
```

The nice thing about BIT over TINYINT/SMALLINT is that if you have between 1-8 BIT columns, they can fit into a single byte.

In all of these cases, you still aren't going to be able to say

```
WHERE NOT BooleanColumn
-- or
WHERE !BooleanColumn
```

You will still have to say

```
WHERE BooleanColumn = 0
```

Comment: I'll bow out my answer and plus one this one. I'll keep out of SQL-Server stuff for the time being...

Comment: @RolandoMySQLDBA I don't know that you had to delete your answer; TINYINT is still an option if the OP can be convinced that he/she doesn't need to store -1, but it offers little over BIT because it is unsigned, requires an additional constraint, and can take up more space if there are multiple columns.

Comment: +1: I'll have to do some quick testing in my front end (MS Access) to see if the 1 vs -1 will be an issue for me.  One thing that I have relied on in the past is doing an `ORDER BY` on a Yes/No column in Access.  In ASC order that means the TRUE items show first then the FALSE ones.  There may be other considerations as well, but your point about up to 8 BIT columns fitting in a single byte is well taken.

Comment: You can use a fairly simple expression for that: `ORDER BY CASE BooleanColumn WHEN 1 THEN -1 ELSE 0 END` ... or you could simply add `DESC` to your order by...

Answer (score 2):

This will do it:

```
MyField smallint NOT NULL CONSTRAINT MyField_YesNo CHECK (MyField = 0 OR MyField = -1)
```

Comment: As discussed by the other answer: the reason to use `SMALLINT` is that `TINYINT` is unsigned, so you have to use a 16-bit field you you insist on using -1 for "true".